# Pandas access Index

Tags: python, pandas

Currently have a Dataframe with a datetime index.  Looking to make a vectorized function that references the index of each row as a key.

For example, I have:

```
>>> sampleset.head()
                               index_h index_l  120l12
time                                                  
2010-05-06T21:00:00.000000000Z       7       2     NaN
2010-05-10T21:00:00.000000000Z     NaN      63     NaN
2010-05-12T21:00:00.000000000Z     NaN      64     1.0
2010-05-14T21:00:00.000000000Z       0     NaN     NaN
2010-05-16T21:00:00.000000000Z       1     NaN     NaN
```

I am trying to access the index values as a key in a function to make a new column.

```
def local_key(dataframe, column, key, ):
    a = sampleset.iloc[sampleset.index.get_loc(key)-5:sampleset.index.get_loc(key)+5][column]
    print(a)
    b = pd.to_numeric(a)
    c = {b.idxmax() : b.max()}
    return c
```

And finally passing

```
sampleset['local'] = local_key(sampleset, 'index_l', sampleset['time'])
```

This function will work fine if I pass an actual key to it, such as:

```
>>> local_key(sampleset, 'index_l', '2010-06-11T21:00:00.000000000Z')
2010-06-03T21:00:00.000000000Z      0
2010-06-04T21:00:00.000000000Z    NaN
2010-06-07T21:00:00.000000000Z      3
2010-06-08T21:00:00.000000000Z    NaN
2010-06-10T21:00:00.000000000Z      4
2010-06-11T21:00:00.000000000Z    NaN
2010-06-12T21:00:00.000000000Z      5
2010-06-14T21:00:00.000000000Z    NaN
2010-06-16T21:00:00.000000000Z      0
2010-06-17T21:00:00.000000000Z    NaN
Name: index_l, dtype: object
{'2010-06-12T21:00:00.000000000Z': 5.0}
```

I am just looking what I need to use in the key variable so I can pass this function to the entire array at once.

Comment: Your question in the last line is unclear. What are you precisely trying to achieve?

Comment: If by vectorized, you mean in terms of speed, mapping this function will be the same speed as, or slower, than a python loop. You want to look into rolling windows. You want the maximum value of +/- 5 rows of the current row?

Comment: Was looking to make my own rolling window in a way.  Your comment on rolling windows got me going int a better direction.  Issue in the first was the get_loc function.  Does not like to be vectorized.   'sampleset['int'] = sampleset.index.get_loc(sampleset['time'])' does not like to play nice.  Essentially making a an integer index along with the datetime index.  Any other keywords would be handy.